# Is there any similar approach to conditional formating for multiple columns from excel in Shiny

Tags: r, excel, shiny, dt

I have a dataframe that is uploaded from excel and displayed as datatable in shiny, in excel we have used conditional formating to change the color of cells based on the values of both the cell itself and the value of other cells. So for example for columns ID, X,Y the logic is as follow:

- if -4 < X < 4 and Y < 10 color of X,Y is pink
- elseif Y >10 color of X,Y is bleu
- else X ="" or Y="" then color of X,Y is white

I tried to use DT package but with no success, could anyone help me to get through this or suggest some other approach? thank you in advance
Here is my code with a reproducible dataframe.

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Column Plot"),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Upload File",
             titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 fileInput('file1', 'Choose xlsx file',
                           accept = c(".xlsx")
                 ),
                 tags$br(),
                 checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
                 radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                              c(Comma=',',
                                Semicolon=';',
                                Tab='\t'),
                              ','),
                 radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                              c(None='',
                                'Double Quote'='"',
                                'Single Quote'="'"),
                              '"')

               ),
               mainPanel(
                 tableOutput('contents')
               )
             )
    ),
tabPanel("contents_extra",
             pageWithSidebar(
               headerPanel('contents_extra'),
               sidebarPanel(
                 checkboxInput('test', 'test', TRUE)

               ),
               mainPanel(
                 dataTableOutput('contents_extra')
               )
             )
    ),
output$contents_extra <- renderDataTable({
      df <- data.frame(
      id = 1:10, 
      X = c(-2, 4, 40, -0.1228, 2.9, 9, 2.7, 2.7, 31, -30),
      Y = c(-18.9, -19.5, 19.6, 12, 11.1, 73, 4.3, 39, 2.5, 1.6),
      A = c(-7.3, 5.1 ,0.12, 15, 21, 1.2, -0,07, 4.3, 39, 2.5) 
      B = c(-18.9, 0.12, 15, 11.1, 73, -2, 4, 40, -19.5, 19.6)
      C = c(4.3, 39, 2.5, 1.6, -7.3, 6, 5.1 ,0.12, -0.07, 4.3)
      library(DT)
      options(DT.options = list(pageLength = 100))
      datatable(df, options = list(
      columnDefs = list(list(targets = X, visible = TRUE)))) %>% formatStyle(
      columns = c("X","Y"),
      valueColumns = c("X","Y"),
      backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(X > -4 && X < 4 && Y < 10, Y > 10, X ="" or Y=""), c('pink', 'bleu','white'))
       )
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question about `DT` (answer is the same whether you use `shiny` or not).

It's easier to derive the colors in R. Then use a `rowCallback`.

```
library(DT)
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:10, 
  X = c(-2, 4, 40, -0.1228, 2.9, 9, 2.7, 2.7, 31, -30),
  Y = c(-18.9, -19.5, 19.6, 12, 11.1, 73, 4.3, 39, 2.5, 1.6)
)
colors <- with(df, ifelse(X > -4 & X < 4 & Y < 10, 
                          "pink", 
                          ifelse(Y > 10, 
                                 "blue", "white")))

rgbcolors <- apply(grDevices::col2rgb(colors), 2, 
                   function(rgb) sprintf("rgb(%s)", paste(rgb, collapse=",")))
columns <- c(2,3) # columns X and Y
jscode <- 
  paste("function(row, data, index) {",  
        sprintf("var colors=%s;\n%s", 
                sprintf("[%s]", 
                        paste(sprintf("'%s'", rgbcolors), collapse=", ")), 
                paste(sprintf("$(this.api().cell(index, %s).node()).css('background-color', colors[index]);", 
                              columns), collapse="\n")), 
        "}", sep="\n")
datatable(df, escape=FALSE, 
          options = list(rowCallback=JS(jscode))
)
```

[image]

The created Javascript code is:

```
> cat(jscode)
function(row, data, index) {
var colors=['rgb(255,192,203)', 'rgb(255,255,255)', 'rgb(0,0,255)', 'rgb(0,0,255)', 'rgb(0,0,255)', 'rgb(0,0,255)', 'rgb(255,192,203)', 'rgb(0,0,255)', 'rgb(255,255,255)', 'rgb(255,255,255)'];
$(this.api().cell(index, 2).node()).css('background-color', colors[index]);
$(this.api().cell(index, 3).node()).css('background-color', colors[index]);
}
```

Comment: @Alexis_543 Can't you use the classical `formatStyle` function for that ?

Comment: One more question, if I wanted to expend your code in which I can apply it to other columns each with its own condition as I added in the original post:

`- For columns A, B,C
- if "A" < 3 then "A" is green else pink
- if "B" < 3 then "B" is green else pink
- if "C" < 3 then "C" is green else pink`

should I add another variable for example "colors_2" with the new columns/conditions and another jscode or it is possible to add it in the existing code?

I tried to understand your code but wasn't able maybe because I have sero knowledge about javascript?

Comment: @Alexis_543 See the last example in `?formatStyle`.

Comment: You mean formatStyle beside your code because I was trying to use it in beginning but I wasn't able to find how to add if-else for multiple column in one condition which you did with jscode and rowCallback. However for one condition in one column It is straight forward with formatStyle but then again is it possible to combine FormateStyle with rowCallback in the same piece of code?

Comment: @Alexis_543 Sorry I'm lost. Maybe you could open a new question? For conditions on a single column, `formatStyle` is appropriate, and you can use several `formatStyle`.

Comment: Sorry if I confused you. The thing is that I want to apply conditions on a single column and conditions on multiple columns on the same datatable. Do you think that doable with only formateStyle?

Comment: I rarely use `DT` but I would try `... %>% formatStyle("A", color=styleInterval(3, c("green","pink"))) %>% formatStyle("B", color=styleInterval(..... `. That does not work ?

Comment: It works if it is used alone (conditions on a single column) but not for conditions on multiple columns (your solution)

Comment: @Alexis_543 We can't continue here. I'm confused. Please open a new question.

Comment: Please find the new question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51594858/single-multiple-conditions-for-columns-formating-with-dt